# How do I send the output into txt file? Do I need to import OS?

Tags: python, txt

Here is the code:

```
import random


def random_gen():
    return f".type('ffi{random.randint(1, 22)}-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}')"


for _ in range(5559999):
    print(random_gen())
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sys library and write random gen to a file. Like the second answer in this thread: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)